# Does "Added Cold Damage Support" add the cold tag to the supported gem?

Tags: path-of-exile

The title basically says everything.

I am running a tornado shot build with added cold support and I wonder, if % crit multiplier to cold skills will affect it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so.
To my knowledge you cannot alter [gem tags](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Gem_tag). Your setup will [add cold damages to every hits](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Added_Cold_Damage_Support) of the main skill, but will not change the attack skill to a cold skill.

In case you don't know, there are very detailed informations about every equipped skills in the [offense](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Character_screen#Offence) section of your character screen. There you can take a look to the `% crit multiplier` of `tornado shot` an see if it is affected directly.
(If you can test it, please tell us the results!)

Comment: This is correct, it will not turn your tornado shot into a cold skill.

Comment: You can "alter" gem tags with totems and traps. Those are the only exceptions however, so you are correct, this won't make it a cold skill.

Comment: I don't get how totems or traps would "alter" tags. `+x level of socketed spell gem` would still affect a spell gem even when supported by `spell totem support`, wouldn't it ? (Albeit the spell will not be usable as a spell skill, but as a totem skill). Could you clarify with a reply or an edit please ?

Comment: So I did test it and you're right. Cold damage support does not alter the supported gem's tags.